# How could I implement a custom StopWatch?

Tags: java, junit

Does Junit have some special annotation could auto calculate the spent time? If so I could avoid manually calculating time, like this:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// do something here
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
log.info("took time: {}", end - start);
assertTrue((end - start) > 1000L);
```

Now I feel `StopWatch` is a little cumbersome:

```
@Rule
public Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch() {
    @Override
    protected void succeeded(long nanos, Description description) {
        logInfo(description, "succeeded", nanos);
    }

    @Override
    protected void failed(long nanos, Throwable e, Description description) {
        logInfo(description, "failed", nanos);
    }

    @Override
    protected void skipped(long nanos, AssumptionViolatedException e, Description description) {
        logInfo(description, "skipped", nanos);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finished(long nanos, Description description) {
        logInfo(description, "finished", nanos);
    }
};
```

Ideally, I want this effect:

```
@Test
@StopWatch
public void test_sleep_1_seconds(){
    sleep1();
    assertTrue(stopwatch.runtime(TimeUnit.SECONDS) > 1L);
}
```

How could I implement the custom `StopWatch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StopWatch](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/Stopwatch.html) is abstract, but it doesn't have any abstract methods, so you don't need to override all of them, but you still have to instantiate an anonymous class, which is slightly less cumbersome:

```
@Rule
public Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch() {};

@Test
public void test_sleep_1_seconds()  {
    sleep1();
    assertTrue(stopwatch.runtime(TimeUnit.SECONDS) > 1);
}
```

Actually, according to [#1110](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/1110), `StopWatch` doesn't need to be abstract and is changed to a regular class. These updates are going to be released in JUnit 4.13.

If you need to check this for all of your tests, you might want to override `succeeded`:

```
@Rule
public Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch() {
    @Override
    protected void succeeded(long nanos, Description description) {
        assertTrue(runtime(TimeUnit.SECONDS) > 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I want to implement a custom StopWatch annotation--MyStopWatch, and directly use it above test method on demand , just like `@Test` `@Before` Could `junit` support it by implement some class?

Comment: @zhuguowei it's possible. I suppose you'll need to implement custom [test runner](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Test-runners) for that